# how to change browser history in java script

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm creating a small web application and I'm loading my pages using ajax in div.

Whenever user click on link, ajax request page and then update my div and url..
after ajax request when i try to refresh my pages,

It's working fine and show me current page but when i click on back button it's change top url but not the page and it's content
here is my code

```
$.ajax({ 
url: link, 
type:'POST', 
data : name, 
success: function(data) { 
$("#main").html(data);  
  history.pushState({foo:'bar'}, title, link);
  }
 }
});
```

Comment: You need to handle the `popstate` event.

Comment: yes i searched it but i didn't understand, cna you please give me some idea how it's work? Thanks

Comment: You're looking for the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Slaks says in the comments, you need to handle the `window.onpopstate`.

Documentation:

> going back doesn't change the document's contents from what they were
>   in the previous step, although the document might update its contents
>   manually upon receiving the `popstate` event.

To do this you need a `State object`, which you pass as a parameter in your `pushState` call. A state Object is a javascript object that is associated with the new history entry. The popstate event is fired only when the active history entry changes and it will have a **copy** of the `State object` as a parameter.
As docs says, `history.pushState()` (and `history.replaceState()`) methods only add (and modify) history entries, for this reason:

> calling `history.pushState()` or `history.replaceState()` won't trigger a popstate event. The popstate event is only triggered by performing a browser action, such as clicking on the back button (or calling `history.back()` in JavaScript), when navigating between two history entries for the same document.